# How can I truncate text within cell

Tags: c#, itext

How I can indicate user with some character like ellipsis that text within cell is truncated if it extends more then fixed height of the cell.

```
pdfTable = new PdfPTable (1);
pdfTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Label Heading", statementLabelFont));
pdfTable.addCell(cell);

StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
for (data : dataList) {
    str.append(data != null ?data.getdata1() :"");
    str.append(strSeparator);           
}

cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setFixedHeight(100f);      
cell.setCellEvent(new TruncateContent(str.toString()));
pdfTable.addCell(cell);

static class TruncateContent implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected String content;

    public TruncateContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
            PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        try {
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
            Font font = new Font(bf, 12);
            float availableWidth = position.getWidth();
            int contentLength = content.length();
            int leftChar = 0;
            int rightChar = contentLength - 1;
            availableWidth -= bf.getWidthPoint("...", 12);

            while (leftChar < contentLength && rightChar != leftChar) {
                availableWidth -= bf.getWidthPoint(content.charAt(leftChar), 12);
                if (availableWidth > 0)
                    leftChar++;
                else
                    break;
                availableWidth -= bf.getWidthPoint(content.charAt(rightChar), 12);
                if (availableWidth > 0)
                    rightChar--;
                else
                    break;
            }

            String newContent = content.substring(0, leftChar) + "..." + content.substring(rightChar);

            PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
            ct.setSimpleColumn(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom(), position.getRight(), position.getTop());
            ct.addElement(new Paragraph(newContent, font));
            ct.go();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't see any reason why the text would be truncated. There is no defined area within the cell, the cell will just expand and show all the data. Please clarify why you think the data is truncated?

Comment: I want to make use of go() and hasMoreText(status) method within cell

Comment: OK, have you tried limiting the height of the cell? Why are you adding content straight to the `PdfPCell` if you want to use `go()`; you should add the content in a cell event if you want to use `hasMoreText()`.

Comment: Read [the official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-rendered-dimensions-text) for an [example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/fit-text-cell#955-truncatetextincell.java). See cell D5 in the [resulting PDF](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/tables/cmp_truncate_cell_content.pdf). The text `"D2 is a cell with more content than we can fit into the cell."` doesn't fit, so we truncate it and we add `"..."` to show that we left part of the content out.

Comment: Thanks.Is ColumnText.setSimpleColumn(Rectangle) is not supported now?

Comment: If it's not supported, you are probably using an obsolete version of iText. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using iText-2.1.7

Comment: Ouch... You know that 2.1.7 [can't be used in a commercial context](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5), don't you? Also, why would you use a version that dates from 2009 when many updates and upgrades have been released since that date. iText 2.1.7 is no.longer supported. It was removed from all official iText sites many years ago

Comment: ok.I will try to upgrade it.

Comment: I tried it is considering cell width available rather then available height.Base Font doesn't have height method to consider.

Comment: What do you mean  when you dsy BaseFont doesn't have height method? If it's average height, you define that using the font size. If it's the height of a specific String you have the ascender and the descender value ( and the difference between those two is the height). Your questions are always very unclear. It's as you're thinking out loud, not really expecting an answer.